# Blender on Linux - list of AMD GPUs that work with Cycles/OpenCL

Tags: rendering, gpu, linux, opencl, compatibility

Which AMD GPUs are useable with a recent Linux, more specifically Ubuntu (18.04) and AMD drivers? Or are there some that definitely don't work?

This question is not off topic because either a GPU evidently works with Blender or it doesn't, so it's not about subjective hardware recommendations.

Thanks in advance.

P.S.: The open source OpenCL implementation of Mesa still doesn't seem to work, or did someone get it to? Because if possible I'd of course use that instead of the AMD drivers.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about hardware recommendations

Comment: It's not that easy, I don't want a recommendation. There are GPUs that work and ones that don't. I could rephrase the question as: "List of working AMD GPUs with Blender on Linux". Isn't that a clear Q&A style question?

Comment: I'm at doubt here. [Rules clearly say hardware is off topic](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1/what-questions-should-be-definitely-off-topic), but not sure if an exception applies here, rephrasing certainly helps. Lets see what others say, I can lift my vote if necessary

Comment: Yeah, it's not as subjective as "whats the best GPU for XY" or something, so lets see

Comment: I would consider it off topic. It is a hardware question and 'afordable' is a matter of opinion. I think hardware questions should definitely not be limited to 'what's the best...'. Should we answer hardware questions? - I really don't care, but if the community guidelines are that there should not be hardware questions here and we want to follow these rules stricktly, then I think this is definitely an off topic question.

Comment: So I reworded parts of the question and removed unnecessary ones ("affordable"), so that objective answers are possible. The guideline BTW says "Hardware specifications, recommendations, reviews or faults". Is one of these still in the question?

Comment: The question is now more about "blender system requirements for GPU compute" than about "best/worst hardware specs", and that makes it on-topic in my opinion

Comment: I think I'll go with the RX580, it seems to be a future-proof choice. What do you think?
I guess I'll try to create the list myself over time, gathering information with links etc. Help is welcome! :-)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about system/hardware compatibility with blender.

Comment: I thought this has been discussed above? Still don't see anything about "hardware compatibility" in the off-topic list. Besides, did you see the answer? I'm trying to create a comprehensive list here (help appreciated), not just for personal use like "What GPU should I buy in XY scenario" but for any Linux user who has the same problems. Isn't this constructive Q&A-Style?

Comment: According to our current rule this would still be off topic (it's more likely about hardware/driver compatibility with the kernel than blender). That said, I think this could fit here, even if it's not normal Q&A material but more of a "list all the things" team effort. We actually already have a such a [canonical](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/q/354/599) post for common GPU problems, so perhaps this could be merged with that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a list of AMD GPUs known running together with OpenCL and Blender Cycles. It is composed by either personal experience or from sources on the web:

```
╔═════════════════════╦═════════╦════════════╦════════════╦════════════╦════════╗
║         GPU         ║   OS    ║ OS version ║ Blender v. ║   Driver   ║ Source ║
╠═════════════════════╬═════════╬════════════╬════════════╬════════════╬════════╣
║    Radeon cards     ║         ║            ║            ║            ║        ║
║ RX580               ║ Xubuntu ║ 18.04.02   ║ 2.8beta    ║ OpenCL-Pro ║      5 ║
║ RX580               ║ Linux*  ║ N/A        ║ 2.79       ║ N/A        ║    1,3 ║
║ RX470 4GB           ║ Kubuntu ║ 16.04      ║ 2.78       ║ AMDGPU-Pro ║      2 ║
║ RX Vega 64          ║ Arch,   ║ N/A        ║ 2.79       ║ AMDGPU &   ║      4 ║
║                     ║ custom kernel, libdrm downgrade   ║ AMD OpenCL ║        ║
║ RX480               ║ Linux*  ║ N/A        ║ 2.79_build ║ N/A        ║      3 ║
║ RX Vega 56          ║ Linux*  ║ N/A        ║ 2.79_build ║ N/A        ║      3 ║
║ RX Vega 64          ║ Linux*  ║ N/A        ║ 2.79_build ║ N/A        ║      3 ║
║ RX Vega Frontier E. ║ Linux*  ║ N/A        ║ 2.79_build ║ N/A        ║      3 ║
║ Pro WX 7100         ║ Linux*  ║ N/A        ║ 2.79_build ║ N/A        ║      3 ║
║ Pro WX 7100 DUO     ║ Linux*  ║ N/A        ║ 2.79_build ║ N/A        ║      3 ║
╚═════════════════════╩═════════╩════════════╩════════════╩════════════╩════════╝
```

<sup>* likely Ubuntu or a derivate (officially supported), see [this comment](https://code.blender.org/2017/11/cycles-benchmark-amd-update-new-benchmark-file/#comment-87441). Also means that AMDs OpenCL implementation must've been used, as there's no other known working so far


sources:
[1](http://blenchmark.com/device-details/Radeon%20RX%20580%20Series), 
[2](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=REQuKDZXfLA),
[3](https://code.blender.org/2017/11/cycles-benchmark-amd-update-new-benchmark-file/)
[4: user gandalf3](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/47281011#47281011)
   5: myself, using Xubuntu 18.04.02 with an all open stack (standard) plus the OpenCL portion from the closed AMDGPU-Pro driver</sup>

This list is obviously far from complete, it's just meant as a start. I'll gather more and more information in the near future.

Feel free to edit, improve and add to this list to complete it and make it comprehensive in the end!

P.S.: The table was made with https://senseful.github.io/text-table/, as the standard SE markdown does not support tables in any way, see [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/73566/is-there-markdown-to-create-tables).

Comment: https://opendata.blender.org/ can be quite useful to look at. For now it contains only user-provided data, but the BI is going to also maintain a set of "verified benchmarks"

Comment: Already had a look into that, thanks. However I found no way of seeing individual data, like a list or something.

Comment: After logging in, you can find a downloadable json dump of all the data, that includes information like ```{"cpu_brand": "AMD Phenom(tm) 9650 Quad-Core Processor", "dist_name": "debian", "dist_version": "9.0",}, "blender_version": {"version": "2.79 (sub 1)"}```